# How do I get the Microsoft CRM 2011 Outlook Plugin to authenticate?

Tags: authentication, outlook-2010, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I just installed Microsoft CRM 2011 on our webserver and I'm trying to get the CRM Outlook Plugin to authenticate to it. When I put in the server URL and click "Test Connection..." I get a dialog box that says "There is a problem communicating with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server. The server might be unavailable. Try again later. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator." I am unable to proceed beyond this point.

Some background info:

1. The client machine I'm connecting from is not a member of the domain (I suspect this is the problem).
2. I am able to connect to CRM just fine via the web interface by specifying my credentials in the username/password box that pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem clearly is that it is not a member of the domain, and therefore, not getting pass-though authentication when they login. You don't really say who you are connecting to, but if it is a hosted application, do they have a single-sign-on application?

If not, I looked at this briefly, and the answer is surely in this document:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3861e56d-b5ed-4f7f-b2fd-5a53bc71dafc&DisplayLang=en